# How to convert html entities in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, windows, oracle-11g, xml, character-set

I'm trying to decode html containing html entities.
I've tried `dbms_xmlgen.convert` and [`utl_i18n.unescape_reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15329390/2936460) but the results are less than satisfactory.

```
SET ESCAPE ON;
SELECT
   'dbms_xmlgen.convert' AS method,
   dbms_xmlgen.convert('\&hearts;', 1) AS hearts,
   dbms_xmlgen.convert('\&amp;',    1) AS amp_ent,
   dbms_xmlgen.convert('\&#0038;',  1) AS amp_dec,
   dbms_xmlgen.convert('\&#x0026;', 1) AS amp_hex,
   dbms_xmlgen.convert('\&#28608;\&#20809;', 1) AS chinese_laser 
FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT
   'utl_i18n.unescape_reference',
   utl_i18n.unescape_reference('\&hearts;'),
   utl_i18n.unescape_reference('\&amp;'),
   utl_i18n.unescape_reference('\&#0038;'),
   utl_i18n.unescape_reference('\&#x0026;'),
   utl_i18n.unescape_reference('\&#28608;\&#20809;') 
FROM dual;
```

The results I get are:

```
METHOD                        HEARTS      AMP_ENT     AMP_DEC     AMP_HEX     CHINESE_LASER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dbms_xmlgen.convert           &hearts;    &           &#0038;     &#x0026;    &#28608;&#20809;
utl_i18n.unescape_reference   ¿           &           &           &           ¿¿
```

My actual problem involves Chinese characters, processed by a Java program to create PDF reports. I have no easy access to the Java code, but I do have control over the query used by the program.

An [example of Chinese characters](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html#whyutf8-user) that I use for testing is 激光, which [Google Translate](https://translate.google.nl/#auto/en/%E6%BF%80%E5%85%89) tells me means 'laser' and which I receive encoded as `&#28608;&#20809;`. These aren't decoded properly, as can be seen in the example above.

I realise that in the second row, the inverted question marks seem to indicate that the entities *were* converted, but can't be displayed properly. However, is this Oracle itself doing this, or the client (I tried in both SQL+ and Toad)? When I plug `utl_i18n.unescape_reference` into the query used by the Java program, it works for entities like `&#177;` (±), but again, not for the Chinese characters.

**How can I have *all* entities properly decoded?**

- Should I use another function? (These were recommended *somewhere on the Internet*).
- Should I change some settings? (Relevant settings shown below).

---

#### Relevant information

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.5.0

NLS_LANGUAGE                           AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY                          AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSET                       WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET                 AL16UTF16
```

Comment: `&hearts;` isn't a standard XML entity (there's very few of those). Could you show an example with one of your Chinese chars, and please specify your locale settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chinese characters are decoded correctly with `utl_i18n.unescape_reference`.  In fact they just aren't displayed properly in your query result which might not support those special characters.

You can confirm that with this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38079).

It is the client which is respsonsible to display the characters appropriately.  If the client can not display a character it may show an upside down question mark, something else or just plain garbage.

So by now, the real question is where do you want to display this string...

Comment: You're correct. I'm surprised the Java client can't handle the characters, so I'll have to look into what happens in there.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you have tried SQL*Plus and Toad; what is your client operating system, Windows? Unix?  See [NLS_OS_CHARSET Environment Variable](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG722) that is an environment variable set on your client to a value that your client understands and supports.  If you are on Unix, invoke the

```
locale
```

command and see what LANG or LC_ALL is set to; you may need to set

export NLS_OS_CHARSET=UTF-8

or the like.

You can list the available locales in Unix with

```
locale -a
```

Comment: I'm on Windows 7.